# Loop through URLS and use ajax request each time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm a beginner in JQuery and I'm trying to use an ajax request inside a for loop.
My ultimate goal would be to iterate through an array of urls, to get the content of each page and search for divs with a specific class, then put the divs' contents in an array. after all pages have been explored i would then count the number of occurrences in the array for each value.

For now I'm just trying to get the ajax request to work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = 'https://peekaboo-rpg.forumactif.com';
    var topic = '/t6203-';
    var sectionUrl = [
    '','p10-','p20-';
    
    for(var i=0; i<=sectionUrl.length; i++){
      var keySearch = url+topic+sectionUrl[i];
      
      $.ajax({
          url:keySearch,
          success:function(data){
            console.log(keySearch);
          }
        });
    }
});
```

This code would simply return the url for each page in the console and actually it returns "undefined" for the sectionUrl part; so when I try to actually fetch my data likes this:

```
lesgens = [].slice.call($(".pab_sujpseudo a span strong", data));
lesnoms = lesgens.map(function(elem) { return elem.innerHTML; });
console.log(lesnoms);
```

it always returns the same values, those from the first item in my array.

Comment: you want to make multiple AJAX requests inside a loop and process the data from each request. The issue you're facing with your code is related to the variable keySearch inside the AJAX success callback.

Comment: The variable keySearch is being overwritten in each iteration of the loop, and when the AJAX request completes and executes the success callback, it references the final value of keySearch.

Comment: Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes I want multiple ajax requests, but actually from what i could gather the keySearch variable isn't being overwritten, it just is undefined for some reason?

Comment: try using let for variable declaration.
`let keySearch = url+topic+sectionUrl[i];`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = 'https://peekaboo-rpg.forumactif.com';
    var topic = '/t6203-';
    var sectionUrl = ['', 'p10-', 'p20-'];

    function fetchData(keySearch) {
        $.ajax({
            url: keySearch,
            success: function(data) {
                var lesGens = [].slice.call($(".pab_sujpseudo a span strong", data));
                var lesNoms = lesGens.map(function(elem) { return elem.innerHTML; });
                console.log(lesNoms);
            }
        });
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < sectionUrl.length; i++) {
        var keySearch = url + topic + sectionUrl[i];
        fetchData(keySearch);
    }
});
```

By declaring lesGens and lesNoms inside the success callback function using var, you ensure that each AJAX request has its own separate variables for storing the data, and they won't overwrite each other.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it works so far! thanks for your advice as well, i have about 80 urls to fetch so that's quite alot... however, for the use of the script i have i think it's ok like this, since i should only be running it for myself once a month... I'm still interested in making the script more efficient tho if you ever have time to explain :)

Comment: Actually sorry to bother you again, it seems keySearch does have the right value for each loop, however data remains always the same?

Comment: I see the issue now. I will edit my response.

Comment: I'm still experimenting the same problem with the new solution, I'm sorry :( Like, even if i just do console.log(data), it always returns the same value for data, although it seems to loop correctly through the urls, and I really don't understand how that could be (EDIT: and the value seems to be associated to the url without the sectionUrl part)

Comment: when i try solution, result seems as below:                                                           
jQuery element Selector                                                                                            
This is p tag                                                                                                                                     
This is span tag
This is div tag

Comment: what is your expectation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255227/discussion-between-amy-and-yasinarli).